# How System reacts to pending request DB2 dump post ITIM 5.1 to ISIM 6.0 upgrade

Tags: import, db2, upgrade, apprequests, tivoli-identity-manager

We are migrating ITIM 5.1 to ISIM6.0. While we are are conducting the upgrade process and testing the new production system, the old production system continues to capture changes made in production. The IBM Security Identity Manager upgrade does not provide a mechanism to capture these changes so we need to import the data from old production system to new one. while importing DB2 dump it is possible that there are few pending requests on old system so when we migrate this data , how system will react to these pending requests? are there any steps we need to execute in order to process these requests on newer production systems or will these pending requests will picked up automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not a Db2 question, instead it is an application-layer question, because the question would be the same regardless of whether the RDBMS was Oracle or SQL-Server or Db2.

Refer to the ISIM knowledge centre for [details of upgrading](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSRMWJ_6.0.0/com.ibm.isim.doc_6.0/installing/tsk/tsk_ic_ins_upg_before.htm).

Some applications don't support online upgrading and need either a complete or partial shut down or some changes in operational procedures, in particular IBM advises:

> "Reduce system activity before starting the upgrade process. Avoid
>   starting policy enforcements or reconciliation requests before
>   upgrading IBM Security Identity Manager. Do not delete entries
>   directly from the SCHEDULED_MESSAGES table in the IBM Security
>   Identity Manager database. "

If you have database-backups secured BEFORE the upgrade, and archive-logging enabled on the databases, and *separate* old and new environments then you can avoid data loss at the cost of some data migration post upgrade.

Upgrade details vary with your configuration.

Upgrading a [single server ITIM instance](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSRMWJ_6.0.0/com.ibm.isim.doc_6.0/installing/tsk/tsk_ic_ins_upg_itim_ssvr.htm)

Upgrading a [clustered configuration](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSRMWJ_6.0.0/com.ibm.isim.doc_6.0/installing/tsk/tsk_ic_ins_upg_itim_cluster.htm)

Comment: If before upgrade there are few pending requests like pending approvals and RFI, so when we import this pending request dumb on new production environment during DB2 upgrade, will these pending requests survive migration? On new production env, these pending requests will get processed or not?